# If I know f(z)=cz in the real line,f(z) is analytic.Can I draw the conclusion that f(z)=cz?

Tags: complex-analysis

If I know $f(z)$=$cz$ in the real line,$f(z)$ is analytic. Can I draw the conclusion that $f(z)=cz$?

If I can't, does there exist some conditions that imply this?

Comment: I guess I can use Schwarz lemma,right?

Comment: When $f(z)=z$ for real $z$ then $f$ might as well be extended to $f(z)=\bar z$, which is not analytic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function $f$ is defined and analytic on a neighborhood of the real line, then yes, it must equal $cz$ on that neighborhood. It is a general fact, for two analytic functions defined on an open set, that if they are equal on a subset that has a limit point inside the open set, then they are equal on the entire open set (this is a strong form of analytic continuation, and follows from the fact that the zeros of an analytic function must be isolated).